# Pagination not working with a foreach loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, foreach, pagination

I have a loop that cycles through every tag and displays 10 posts from each tag. This works, but I want to set it to only show 20 posts on each page overall, so page 1 shows tag 1 posts, tag 2 posts, then page 2 shows tag 3 posts, tag 4 posts etc

I'm not sure how to do this. Do I need to put the foreach loop in another array and define posts_per_page in the new array? Or does it maybe require setting up a function with pre_get_posts?

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$car_group_terms = get_terms( 'post_tag' );

foreach ( $car_group_terms as $car_group_term ) {
            $car_group_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'car_listing',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( $car_group_term->slug ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ) );

 while ($car_group_query->have_posts() ) : $car_group_query->the_post(); 
    get_template_part( 'content', 'car_listing' ); 
    }
    endwhile; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show posts from two tags on each page, I think the best approach would be to query only those two tags on the "get_terms" function. Also, I think you'll have to create your own paging because the paging is per query and since you're creating a custom one, the standard paging will not apply.

Also, if you're doing it all in a page template, you should use "page" instead of the "paged" query var. If it's an archive page (or any none single page) the the "paged" var is fine. In the code below I considered both options.

```
<?php
        if (get_query_var('paged')) { /* in case the code is on an archive/taxonomy page */
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
            $nextpage = add_query_arg('paged', $paged + 1, get_permalink()); /* for paging later */
            $prevpage = add_query_arg('paged', $paged - 1, get_permalink());
        } elseif (get_query_var('page')) { /* in case the code is on a single page */
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
            $nextpage = add_query_arg('page', $paged + 1, get_permalink());
            $prevpage = add_query_arg('page', $paged - 1, get_permalink());
        } else {
            $paged = 1;
            if(!is_single() && !is_page()) { /* since there is no corresponding query var, need to check by type of page */
                $nextpage = add_query_arg('paged', $paged + 1, get_permalink());
                $prevpage = add_query_arg('paged', $paged - 1, get_permalink());
            } else {
                $nextpage = add_query_arg('page', $paged + 1, get_permalink());
                $prevpage = add_query_arg('page', $paged - 1, get_permalink());
            }
        }


        $number_per_page = 2; /* number of tags to show per page */

        $car_count = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'fields' => 'count', /* returns only number of terms for paging purpose */
        ));

        $number_of_pages = $car_count / $number_per_page; /* get the total amount of pages */

        $car_group_terms = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'number' => $number_per_page,
            'offset' => $number_per_page * ($paged - 1) /* offset to show the correct tags according to page number */
        ));


        foreach ($car_group_terms as $car_group_term) {

            /* Do What ever you want to do with each tag here */

        }

        /** paging **/
        if ($paged < $number_of_pages) {
            echo '<a href="' . $nextpage . '">Next Page</a> ';
        }

        if ($paged < $number_of_pages && $paged > 1) {
            echo ' | ';
        }

        if ($paged > 1) {
            echo '<a href="' . $prevpage . '">Previous Page</a> ';
        }

        /** /paging **/
        ?>
```

Replace the "/* Do What ever you want to do with each tag here */" with your own code. I didn't copy it to my answer because you have some problem there with the curled brackets and it's irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: Uri you're a legend. That worked first time. I spent the entire day yesterday trying to figure this out. Just couldn't figure out the paging. Thanks!

Comment: @mark914 Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark.